# How to add rows and past below last item- excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a Macro that will help with a monthly task. So far, I recorded the below that manipulates column N with text-to-columns, then copies the entire column into a new tab called 'Remove Duplicates'. Then the duplicates from that column are removed. From here, I want to insert 4 rows below each remaining items in column B, after the duplicates are removed. I don't know how to write the code so that it stops inserting rows if there is no more text below.

```
Columns("O:O").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("N:N").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("N1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :="-", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Columns("N:N").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Remove Duplicates").Select
Columns("B:B").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$B$104").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
Rows("4:7").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Rows("9:12").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Rows("14:17").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Rows("19:22").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Rows("24:27").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Rows("29:32").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Rows("34:38").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

In those 4 rows, the text can just say 'item 1', 'item2', 'item3', and 'item4'. So for example, if after removing duplicates I am left with 5 rows of text in Column B, I want to insert 20 rows, 4 below each existing rows (although the last row probably doesn't need any new rows inserted since there is nothing below it). Then in each of those new 4 rows, it should say 'item1', item2', etc., respectively.

Lastly, if possible, I would like to copy all the rows in column B, and paste it into a new tab, called 'Summary'. This tab will already have a list of items, also in column B, and I would like to paste the new rows at the bottom of this list, just adding on to it.

Is there a way to create some code that can accomplish this?

My apologies if this is confusing. I can answer questions on anything that is unclear.

Thanks in advance!

---

So with the code provided below (I expanded it to 6 rows), plus some research on my own, I managed to get the additional rows, as well as the copy and paste to the bottom of another tab up-and-running. Here is my current code:

```
    Columns("O:O").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("N:N").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("N1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :="-", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Columns("N:N").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Remove Duplicates").Select
Columns("B:B").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$B$104").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim rowCnt As Long
For rowCnt = lastRow To 4 Step -1

Range("B" & rowCnt).Resize(6, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, 
CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Next

Sheets("Data").Select
Rows("5:5").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("All Entries").Select

Dim lrow As Long

lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Range("A" & lrow).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

The last piece, if anyone can help, is adding the same set of text (call it 'item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4', 'item 5', 'item 6') to each of the newly added 6 lines. Really appreciate all the help so far!

Comment: You are asking us to write your code for you. You have not shown any effort to accomplish your desired task and where it's not working. Please read about [mcve] and update your question so it's within the scope of how SO works.

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't see the guidelines. I am completely unsure how to even start with creation of that code, so if this goes against the guidelines I understand if no one wants to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming rows of data start on B2 try this code to insert 4 lines after each data row.

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim rowCnt As Long
For rowCnt = lastRow To 3 Step -1

    Range("B" & rowCnt).Resize(4, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Next
```

Comment: would you be able to help me add text to those 4 lines? it would be the same set of texts for each group. If you have any resources that can help, as I realize I'm just asking people for help without providing much assistance on my end.

Comment: If this answer solved your question, please mark as answered. If you have another question please post a new question and someone can help with that. Read [ask] to learn about how to best ask a question on SO to ensure it's answered.